# xbindkeys escape quotes

Tags: bash, pulse-audio, escape-characters, xbindkeys

How can I escape quotes in .xbindkeysrc commands? Neither of those work.

```
"pacmd dump|awk --non-decimal-data '$1~/set-sink-volume/{system ("pacmd "$1" "$2" "$3+2500)}'"

"pacmd dump|awk --non-decimal-data '\$1~/set-sink-volume/{system ("pacmd "\$1" "\$2" "\$3+2500)}'"

"pacmd dump|awk --non-decimal-data '\$1~/set-sink-volume/{system (\"pacmd \"\$1\" \"\$2\" \"\$3+2500)}'"

"pacmd dump|awk --non-decimal-data '$1~/set-sink-volume/{system (\"pacmd \"$1\" \"$2\" \"$3+2500)}'"
```

(The commands raises the PulseAudio volume level)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two separate issues here, and I'll try to address both.

The first is how to correctly quote a command in `.xbindkeysrc`.

All you have to do is take a command that works in `bash`, then put double quotes around it.

For example, for a command with a space in it, you'd have to run

```
"/home/user/My Programs/progname"
```

or

```
/home/user/My\ Programs/progname
```

in `bash`.

Which means you need

```
""/home/user/My Programs/progname""
```

or

```
"/home/user/My\ Programs/progname"
```

in your `.xbindkeysrc`.

Technically what's happening is that xbindkeys removes the outermost pair of double quotes, then runs the remaining string using `sh -c`.

---

In your example, the command

```
pacmd dump|awk --non-decimal-data '$1~/set-sink-volume/{system ("pacmd "$1" "$2" "$3+2500)}'
```

works fine in bash, so I think the problem is elsewhere.

Try running `xbindkeys` with the `-v` option, which makes `xbindkeys` run in the foreground, so you can see any errors on your terminal.

In my case, it shows the underlying cause is not bad quoting, but `pacmd` giving an error

```
...
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

but if you have PulseAudio working, I think you need to change `pacmd` to `pactl`, because the man page says that `pacmd` doesn't take arguments, and several other examples on the web show using `pactl` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, putting the command in double quotes with no escaping at all worked :)

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, create a shell script ~/bin/mychangevolume with the commands non-escaped as they would appear on the command line. Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
incr=$1
pacmd dump | awk --non-decimal-data '$1~/set-sink-volume/{system ("pacmd "$1" "$2" "$3'$incr')}'"
```

Then call this script from .xbindkeysrc

```
"mychangevolume +2500"
```